# Vertical Alignment in Array Environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I have produced the following array

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
{}          &  {\bf{b}}_1  &  {\bf{b}}_2   &  {\bf{b}}_3  \\
\hline
{\bf{a}}_1  &  \cos\theta  &  -\sin\theta  &  0  \\
{\bf{a}}_2  &  \sin\theta  &  \cos\theta   &  0  \\
{\bf{a}}_3  &      0       &       0       &  1  \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

where the output looks like

[image]

How can I vertically align the `sin` and `cos` in the second column?

Comment: `$\phantom{-}\cos\theta$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could insert a `\phantom{-}` instruction immediately before `\cos\theta` in the second row.

Oh, and don't use `\bf` -- use `\mathbf` instead. `\bf` has been deprecated in LaTeX documents since 1994. It still works with the `article`, `report`, and `book` document classes, but it no longer works with the KOMA-script and `memoir` classes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
     &  \mathbf{b}_1  &  \mathbf{b}_2   &  \mathbf{b}_3  \\
\hline
\mathbf{a}_1  &  \cos\theta  &            -\sin\theta  &  0 \\
\mathbf{a}_2  &  \sin\theta  &  \phantom{-}\cos\theta  &  0 \\
\mathbf{a}_3  &      0       &                  0      &  1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To make the array more "beautiful" -- a criterion you've mentioned in a follow-up comment :-) -- you may want to both fine-tune the horizontal positioning of the second and third data columns *and* give the entire array a more "open" look, e.g., by using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{\qquad}c@{}}
\toprule
& \mathbf{b}_1 & \phantom{-}\mathbf{b}_2 & \mathbf{b}_3 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
\mathbf{a}_1  &  \cos\theta  &            -\sin\theta & 0 \\
\mathbf{a}_2  &  \sin\theta  &  \phantom{-}\cos\theta & 0 \\
\mathbf{a}_3  &      0       &  \phantom{-}0          & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe adding \phantom{-} next to zero in the third row makes it look better. Thanks. :)

Comment: @H.R. - Probably. If you go that route, you should also prefix `\phantom{-}` to `\mathbf{b}_2`, right?

Comment: Yes! :) and also to the third column! :)

Comment: I feel that it just looks more beautiful! :)

Comment: @H.R. - I've posted an addendum showing further attempts at beautification. :-)

Comment: Many thanks Mico, I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Another option in *this* case is to use an `r` column alignment for the data and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` to center the headings and zero:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\Mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c|rrc}
\hline
     &  \Mc{\mathbf{b}_1}  &  \Mc{\mathbf{b}_2}   &  \Mc{\mathbf{b}_3}  \\
\hline
\mathbf{a}_1  &  \cos\theta  & -\sin\theta  &  0 \\
\mathbf{a}_2  &  \sin\theta  &  \cos\theta  &  0 \\
\mathbf{a}_3  &    \Mc{0}     &    \Mc{0}   &  1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the attention. :)